# Get access to ssl domain certificate

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate, hosting

I've got the SSL certificate to my domain using hosting Sprinthost. Now I want to know how can I get this certificate to encrypt and decrypt some data?

 - I'm using web-server Node.js and JavaScript for this project. Node server situated on hosting.

 - CA - Lets`Encrypt

 - Type of certificate - wildcard (domain validation).

 - Of course I have access to the shell.

Comment: The easiest way is to make some Ajax request from your frontend js to your https server. Or do everything on server side, accessing file content from node isn't a big deal.

Comment: Yeah, i know that and i want do that on server side, but the question is where can i find the certificate, which was given me by hosting.